# FFmpeg seeking (-ss) not working on some devices

Tags: android, ffmpeg

As the title states, `-ss` command is not working on some devices, like the Huawei Mate 10.

Here is the command I'm using and how I get the values:

```java
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("00:" + "mm:ss.SS");
// Video duration
long duration = getDuration();
// Video duration devided by 6 (I want to get 5 images)
long img1 = duration / 6;
String firstThumbTime = formatter.format(img1);
// Screen dimentions devided by 7
String dimentions = width + ":" + height;

String[] a = {"-ss", firstThumbTime, "-i", mStringFilePath, "-vframes", "1", "-s", dimentions, imageThumbsDirectory + "/" + "thumb1.bmp"};
```

The command above looks like this:

```
-ss 00:00:00.47 -i /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.package/files/MyVideos/2020_02_19_16_00_20.mp4 -vframes 1 -s 154:274 /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.package/files/ThumbTemp/thumb1.bmp
```

The strange thing is that it completes without an error, but the output file is unreadable.

I do not have the logs currently, but I have a user that can send it to me if you need it.

---

I'm 100% sure that it is caused by `-ss` because I use a similar command for trimming a video elsewhere in my application and when the user exports the video without setting trimming points(`-ss`), then the video works.

Here is the 2 command I use for trimming a video:

**Working:**

```
String[] s = {"-i", videonInputPath, "-crf", "18", "-c:v", "libx264", "-preset", "ultrafast", videoOutputPath};
```

**Not working**

```
String[] s = {"-ss", startValue, "-i", videonInputPath, "-crf", "18", "-c:v", "libx264", "-preset", "ultrafast", videoOutputPath};
```

---

This is the first time a user sends me this issue, so it has to be something with his device.

Any advice would greatly be appreciated.

---

**EDIT:**

Log as requested by @Gyan in the comment section below (Added `-v 48` to command):

```
ffmpeg version n4.0-39-gda39990 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 4.9.x (GCC) 20150123 (prerelease)
configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-ffprobe --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-yasm --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-linux-perf --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-nonfree --enable-network --enable-avresample --enable-avformat --enable-avcodec --enable-indev=lavfi --enable-hwaccels --enable-ffmpeg --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-small --enable-nonfree --pkg-config=pkg-config --pkg-config-flags=--static --prefix=/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-cxxflags=
libavutil 56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
libavcodec 58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
libavformat 58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
libavdevice 58. 3.100 / 58. 3.100
libavfilter 7. 16.100 / 7. 16.100
libavresample 4. 0. 0 / 4. 0. 0
libswscale 5. 1.100 / 5. 1.100
libswresample 3. 1.100 / 3. 1.100
libpostproc 55. 1.100 / 55. 1.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-ss' ... matched as option 'ss' (set the start time offset) with argument '00:30:02.58'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument '/storage/emulated/0/Download/email/VID-20180720-WA0001.mp4'.
Reading option '-v' ... matched as option 'v' (set logging level) with argument '48'.
Reading option '-vframes' ... matched as option 'vframes' (set the number of video frames to output) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-s' ... matched as option 's' (set frame size (WxH or abbreviation)) with argument '154:308'.
Reading option '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.package/files/ThumbTemp/thumb1.bmp' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option v (set logging level) with argument 48.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url /storage/emulated/0/Download/email/VID-20180720-WA0001.mp4.
Applying option ss (set the start time offset) with argument 00:30:02.58.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: /storage/emulated/0/Download/email/VID-20180720-WA0001.mp4.
[NULL @ 0xf1fa5000] Opening '/storage/emulated/0/Download/email/VID-20180720-WA0001.mp4' for reading
[file @ 0xf1f94000] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xf1fa5000] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 probed with size=2048 and score=100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xf1fa5000] ISO: File Type Major Brand: mp42
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xf1fa5000] Unknown dref type 0x206c7275 size 12
Last message repeated 1 times
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xf1fa5000] rfps: 29.833333 0.018442
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xf1fa5000] rfps: 29.916667 0.003419
Last message repeated 1 times
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xf1fa5000] rfps: 30.000000 0.000764
Last message repeated 1 times
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xf1fa5000] rfps: 60.000000 0.003057
Last message repeated 1 times
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xf1fa5000] rfps: 120.000000 0.012228
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xf1fa5000] rfps: 29.970030 0.000295
Last message repeated 1 times
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xf1fa5000] rfps: 59.940060 0.001178
Last message repeated 1 times
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xf1fa5000] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 6937 bytes read:32768 seeks:0 nb_streams:2
[h264 @ 0xf1fda380] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 1
[h264 @ 0xf1fda380] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 1
[h264 @ 0xf1fda380] nal_unit_type: 6, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0xf1fda380] nal_unit_type: 5, nal_ref_idc: 1
[h264 @ 0xf1fda380] Format yuv420p chosen by get_format().
[h264 @ 0xf1fda380] Reinit context to 848x480, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xf1fa5000] All info found
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xf1fa5000] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 67446 bytes read:67446 seeks:0 frames:45
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Download/email/VID-20180720-WA0001.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand : mp42
minor_version : 1
compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
creation_time : 2018-07-20T19:57:44.000000Z
Duration: 00:00:15.52, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1679 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und), 1, 1/600: Video: h264, 1 reference frame (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, left), 848x480, 0/1, 1622 kb/s, 30.02 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
Metadata:
rotate : 90
creation_time : 2018-07-20T19:57:44.000000Z
handler_name : Core Media Video
Side data:
displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
Stream #0:1(und), 44, 1/44100: Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 53 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time : 2018-07-20T19:57:44.000000Z
handler_name : Core Media Audio
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.package/files/ThumbTemp/thumb1.bmp.
Applying option vframes (set the number of video frames to output) with argument 1.
Applying option s (set frame size (WxH or abbreviation)) with argument 154:308.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.package/files/ThumbTemp/thumb1.bmp.
Successfully opened the file.
detected 8 logical cores
[h264 @ 0xf1fdbf80] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 1
[h264 @ 0xf1fdbf80] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 1
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> bmp (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0xf1fdbf80] nal_unit_type: 5, nal_ref_idc: 1
[h264 @ 0xf1fdbf80] Format yuv420p chosen by get_format().
[h264 @ 0xf1fdbf80] Reinit context to 848x480, pix_fmt: yuv420p
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0xf1fdc300] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 1
[h264 @ 0xf1fdc680] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0xf1fdca00] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0xf1fdcd80] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0xf1fdd100] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0xf1fdd480] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0xf1fdd800] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 1
[h264 @ 0xf1fddb80] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 1
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xf1fe9360] Setting 'video_size' to value '848x480'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xf1fe9360] Setting 'pix_fmt' to value '0'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xf1fe9360] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/600'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xf1fe9360] Setting 'pixel_aspect' to value '0/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xf1fe9360] Setting 'sws_param' to value 'flags=2'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xf1fe9360] Setting 'frame_rate' to value '30000/1001'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xf1fe9360] w:848 h:480 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/600 fr:30000/1001 sar:0/1 sws_param:flags=2
[transpose @ 0xf1fe9420] Setting 'dir' to value 'clock'
[scaler_out_0_0 @ 0xf1fe9540] Setting 'w' to value '154'
[scaler_out_0_0 @ 0xf1fe9540] Setting 'h' to value '308'
[scaler_out_0_0 @ 0xf1fe9540] Setting 'flags' to value 'bicubic'
[scaler_out_0_0 @ 0xf1fe9540] w:154 h:308 flags:'bicubic' interl:0
[format @ 0xf1fe95a0] Setting 'pix_fmts' to value 'bgra|bgr24|rgb565le|rgb555le|rgb444le|rgb8|bgr8|rgb4_byte|bgr4_byte|gray|pal8|monob'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0xf1fb20c0] query_formats: 7 queried, 6 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
[scaler_out_0_0 @ 0xf1fe9540] picking bgr24 out of 12 ref:yuv420p alpha:0
[transpose @ 0xf1fe9420] w:848 h:480 dir:1 -> w:480 h:848 rotation:clockwise vflip:0
[scaler_out_0_0 @ 0xf1fe9540] w:480 h:848 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 -> w:154 h:308 fmt:bgr24 sar:0/1 flags:0x4
Output #0, image2, to '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.package/files/ThumbTemp/thumb1.bmp':
Metadata:
major_brand : mp42
minor_version : 1
compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
encoder : Lavf58.12.100
Stream #0:0(und), 0, 1001/30000: Video: bmp, 1 reference frame, bgr24(left), 154x308, 0/1, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
Metadata:
encoder : Lavc58.18.100 bmp
creation_time : 2018-07-20T19:57:44.000000Z
handler_name : Core Media Video
Side data:
displaymatrix: rotation of -0.00 degrees
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0xf1fdbf80] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0xf1fdc300] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0xf1fdc680] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0xf1fdca00] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0xf1fdcd80] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0xf1fdd100] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0xf1fdd480] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
Last message repeated 9 times
[out_0_0 @ 0xf1fe94e0] EOF on sink link out_0_0:default.
No more output streams to write to, finishing.
frame= 0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed= 0x 
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Input file #0 (/storage/emulated/0/Download/email/VID-20180720-WA0001.mp4):
Input stream #0:0 (video): 16 packets read (153990 bytes); 16 frames decoded; 
Input stream #0:1 (audio): 0 packets read (0 bytes); 
Total: 16 packets (153990 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.package/files/ThumbTemp/thumb1.bmp):
Output stream #0:0 (video): 0 frames encoded; 0 packets muxed (0 bytes); 
Total: 0 packets (0 bytes) muxed
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
16 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
[AVIOContext @ 0xf1fbc000] Statistics: 221436 bytes read, 1 seeks
```

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: @Gyan Please give me some time to ask the user to send me the log, I will update my question as soon as I get the log.

Comment: ffmpeg builds are probably pretty platform-independent; the root cause of the issue is much more likely the construction of the input file.

Comment: @Gyan Sorry for the long wait, I had to wait for the user to send the log, please see EDIT 1.

Comment: @Gyan I have also included the log from my device using the same input file.

Comment: Will need to see more detailed logs, with `-v 48` added.

Comment: @Gyan Please see the log (`EDIT`) with `-v 48` added

Comment: Your video is `00:00:15.52` long but the seek point is `00:30:02.58` so the seek will not return any media data.

Comment: @Gyan I noticed this right before you replied. Is there any way of passing milliseconds instead of `00:00:00.000`?

Comment: Either `HH:MM:SS.mmm` or `SS.mmm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with `FFmpeg`. It was the way I converted the time to `HH:MM:SS.mmm`. I fixed it by using the following:

```java
private String gethhmmss(long milliseconds) {
    String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d", 
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milliseconds),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliseconds) % TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(1),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(milliseconds) % TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(1),
        milliseconds % 1000);
    return hms;
}
```